# Android nested scrollview anchored to AppBArLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

So, I have a situation, I need to create something like this:

[image]

Where white background view is nested view, and the image with all the elements is in the appbar. Now, I managed to create it without `NestedScrollView` being over the `AppbarLayout`, but how can I achieve that, how can I put `NestedScrollView` above `AppBarLayout` without loosing any functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oreder to make this work, you need to do following:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Where overlapTop is how much it will overlap and layout_behavior is the thing you need here. Hope it helps.